# Prestashop - quantity increase of product

Tags: prestashop

my client insists on showing price per one product but allowing only to buy odd number of products of some category type (f.ex. glasses are sold in packages per 2, but whole pack is too expensive for him to show it in one).

Setting a minimum quantity don't solve my problem because more than two are as well three but we can't split the package.

Any advices?

Comment: You will need to override the method `CartCore::updateQty` and change the behaviour or hook your module into `actionCartSave` and modify the quantity of products everytime a change is made to the cart

Comment: I see, I have to get deeper into code, thanks a lot.